# Installing cakedc/users on CakePHP 3.1 version conflict

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakedc

I'm trying to install Cake dc users on a Cakephp 3.1

That's a part of my composer.json that I'm almost sure that is properly setup mantain the cake version to 3.1:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.1",
```

I used the following command to setup cake:

**composer create-project cakephp/app ar2016-2 3.1.***

and that's the result I get when I try to install DCUsers with the composer:

---

composer require cakedc/users:~3.1.0
./composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1
    - cakedc/users 3.1.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.1.0, 3.1.0-RC1, 3.1.0-beta, 3.1.0-beta2, 3.1.1, 3.1.10, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9].
...

---

It looks that it detects CakePHP 3.2.1 but everywhere I check show me that I'm using the proper 3.1. version. Any Idea?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 1):

I'd doubt that it shows that you've installed `3.1` anywhere at all, because the latest release is `3.2.1` and, `~3.1` means `>= 3.1 and < 4.0.0`, and therefore I'm pretty sure that you have the latest version installed, ie `3.2.1`, a quick `bin/cake` will probably confirm that.

**https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde**

The `cakedc/users` version that you have requested, requires `cakephp/cakephp:3.1.*`, which means `>= 3.1 and < 3.2`, hence the error.

**https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#wildcard**

So either use the `master` branch of the plugin (it requires `cakephp/cakephp:~3.1`) until a proper release is issued, or use a more specific version constraint for the CakePHP framework, like `3.1.*`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer but it's just fixed, it was a problem of the plugin itself and cakedc fixed.